# Expected value inequality for $\min(1,Z)$

Tags: probability, expected-value

I was wondering if any of you folks could help me with this probability problem. I need to show the following inequality:
$$E[\min(1,Z)] \geq \frac{2E[\sqrt{Z}]^2}{1+E[Z]}$$
for Z an almost certainly positive or zero random variable and not constant.
(I already notice that $\min(1,z)$ has the same density as z when $t<1$ and $0$ elsewhere)

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly that $E[\sqrt{Z}]^2 =( E[\sqrt{Z}])^2$?

Comment: yes. you are right

Comment: The inequality is false. Example: $Z$ uniform on $[0,1]$

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly then it might not be true in general. Take $Z=4$ with probability one, then left hand side of your proposed inequality is $=1$, and the right hand side is equal to $\frac{2\times ([\sqrt{4}])^2}{1+4} = \frac{8}{5}$. Let me know if I've misunderstood or miscalculated anything.

Edit after OP's comment: Let $Z$ be a random variable that takes the value $4$ with probability $1/2$, and takes the values $3$ and $5$ each with probability $1/4$. Then clearly $E[Z] = 4$, and $E[\sqrt{Z}] = 2 \times\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{3}\times\frac{1}{4}+ \sqrt{5}\times\frac{1}{4} \approx 1.992$. Now in your proposed inequality left side is $=1$, and the right hand side is $\approx 1.587$.

Another very easy counterexample provided by @leonbloy is: $Z\sim Uniform[0,1]$.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that Z must not be constant

Comment: I have posted another counterexample when $Z$ is not a constant. Best

Comment: Another counterxample: take $Z$ uniform on $[0,1]$

Comment: @leonbloy that is indeed a nice counterexample. Would you mind if I add that to the answer?

Comment: of course, go ahead